# Turning off logging output in activerecord sqlite3 adaptor in ruby

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sqlite

I use the ActiveRecord-gem for accessing a sqlite3-database, all without Rails. I use it like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => "sqlite3", :database => name_file )

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  if ! table_exists? "db_table"
    do_something
  end
end
```

And then I get an output like

```
-- table_exists?("db_table")
   -> 0.0048s
```

Which I don't want. According to different posts, a simple

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil
```

should do the trick. But this is already nil...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those look like migration messages. This should help:

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.verbose = false
```